# Algebraic degree of accuracy of numerical integration operator

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

I have an approximation operator $\hat I(f) = \sum A_i f(x_i)$ for $\int _a^bf$.

Prove that $\hat I$ has zero error for the interpolation polynomial of $f$ of degree $n$, 
iff  it has zero error for any polynomial of degree at most $n$.

Now, it is trivial that if it has zero error for polynomials of degree at most $n$ then it has zero error for the interpolation polynomial, however I don't have a clue about the other direction, becuase I don't see why if it is exact for one polynomial of degree $n$ then it is exact for all of them. I can't just build from the elemantry functions $1, x, x^2, ...$ and use the linear combination because I am given accuracy for the whole polynomial. Isn't it possible that there are errors for parts of the polynomial (polynomials of smaller degrees), but the linear combination is exact?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I understand now. Suppose the degree of some polynomial $P$ is $i<n$, then the interpolation polynomial of degree $n$ of $P$ is $P$, and so the approximation is exact.